# Declare a clone function to make readonly properties writable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have read only data in typescript and a `clone` function:

```
class Data {
    readonly foo: string;
}

const ro: Data = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
// how to declare clone so that it returns writable data?
declare function clone<T>(val: T): T;

const rw = clone(ro);
// how to make the properties of rw writable?
rw.foo = 'changed';
```

How to declare the `clone` function so that the properties of the object it returns are writable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is an even newer way to accomplish this, but I don't think updating the answer that's already here would be the best way to document this.

```
type Mutable<T> = {
    -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
};
```

This has the additional benefits of preserving optional modifiers and only requiring one generic parameter.

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Mutable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20-readonly%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ro%3A%20Data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20'bar'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20clone%3CT%3E(val%3A%20T)%3A%20Mutable%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20rw%20%3D%20clone(ro)%3B%0D%0Arw.foo%20%3D%20'changed'%3B))

Comment: When I hit "run" in the playground, I get the error `[ERR]: clone is not defined`

Comment: @Adam you may want to check out the type-fest library, that should stay up to date with all the latest changes from TypeScript and will provide a number of utility types for you to use in your TypeScript projects: https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest

Answer (score 5):

The current way of doing that is:

```
type Mutable<T extends { [x: string]: any }, K extends string> = {
    [P in K]: T[P];
}

declare function clone<T>(val: T): Mutable<T, keyof T>;
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Mutable%3CT%20extends%20%7B%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%2C%20K%20extends%20string%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20K%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20ro%3A%20Data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20%27bar%27%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20clone%3CT%3E(val%3A%20T)%3A%20Mutable%3CT%2C%20keyof%20T%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20rw%20%3D%20clone(ro)%3B%0D%0Arw.foo%20%3D%20%27changed%27%3B))

As explained here: [Mapped Types syntax to remove modifiers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13723).

---

#### Original answer:

I'm pretty sure that there's no way of removing `readonly` restriction, for example:

```
declare function clone<T>(val: T): {[K in keyof T]: T[K]};
const rw = clone(ro);
rw.foo = 'changed';
```

Still produces the readonly error.

You can do the opposite though, start with a "writeable" interface and restrict that to readonly:

```
interface Data {
    foo: string;
}

const ro: Readonly<Data> = {
    foo: 'bar'
}
declare function clone<T>(val: Readonly<T>): T;

const rw = clone(ro);
rw.foo = 'changed';
```

Note that I've changed `Data` from class to interface because you're not using it as a class in your example.
If you want to use it as a class you need to instantiate it:

```
const ro = new Data();
ro.foo = "bar";
```

Or

```
const ro = Object.assign(new Data(), { foo: "bar" });
```

---

#### The previous edit was using a bug which was mistakenly used:

I take it back, you can in fact ignore the readonly modifier:

```
declare function clone<T>(val: T): {[K in (keyof T)]: T[K]};
const rw = clone(ro);
rw.foo = 'changed';
```

Works fine, the difference is `(keyof T)` instead of just `keyof T`, there's an issue on that: [Mapped Type bug with modifiers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13724) which is marked as a bug.

Comment: unfortunately, I am not in control of making the data readonly (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8e2708ca2118472ca8a3071c21bfe7a5250b911d/react/index.d.ts#L181) I get readonly data and I want to create a writable clone.

Comment: Cool `declare function clone<T>(val: T): {[K in keyof T]: T[K]};` that works!

Comment: @NitzanTomer, if the updated answer is known bug, wouldn't the new answer become deprecated when the bug is fixed? (assuming the dev wanted to use the latest TS)

Comment: @MetroSmurf No, that will still be how you'd use it. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @NitzanTomer - The linked Issue #13724 states "Putting parenthesis around the "keyof T" syntax in an inline Mapped Type, strips out the field modifier (readonly)." - maybe I'm misunderstanding, but isn't the Issue specifically stating the inclusion of the parenthesis stripping out modifier is the bug? Or is that the expected behavior which would be different than the exclusion of the parenthesis?

Comment: @MetroSmurf That's a good question! I'm not sure. I commented in the issue and will update here.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Updated

Comment: @NitzanTomer - Thanks for following up; great clarification. +1 from me.

Comment: @MetroSmurf Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative which worked for me:

```
let config = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(require('src/assets/config.json')));
```

In my case the variable `config` gets readonly for some reason if I use `require` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a TypeScript version of a deep clone function. It's taken from https://javascript.plainenglish.io/deep-clone-an-object-and-preserve-its-type-with-typescript-d488c35e5574 with some modifications:

```
/**
 * Performs a deep clone of an object.
 * https://javascript.plainenglish.io/deep-clone-an-object-and-preserve-its-type-with-typescript-d488c35e5574
 *
 * @param source: The object to clone.
 * @param preservePropertyDescriptor: Whether to preserve thee property descriptor. To see what this contains, refer to:
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor
 * @param excludedProperties A string or array of strings representing property names you do not want to copy into (at
 * any level) of the cloned object.
 *
 * @returns string A Mutable version of the source object.
 *
 */
export const deepCopy: Function = <T>(source: T, preservePropertyDescriptor: boolean = false,
                                      ...excludedProperties: string[]): Mutable<T> => {
  return Array.isArray(source)
    ? source.map((item: T): Mutable<T> => deepCopy(item, preservePropertyDescriptor, excludedProperties))
    : source instanceof Date
     ? new Date(source.getTime())
     : source && typeof source === 'object'
       ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).reduce((obj: any, prop: string): Mutable<T> => {
           if (excludedProperties.includes(prop)) { // skip property
             return obj;
           } else {
             if (preservePropertyDescriptor) {
               Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, prop));
             }
             // @ts-ignore
             obj[prop] = deepCopy(source[prop], preservePropertyDescriptor, excludedProperties);
             return obj;
           }
         }, Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(source)))
       : source as Mutable<T>;
};
```

Comment: Great answer, but I was looking for the declaration not the implementation (I wanted to add types to an existing clone library)