# Deep-Copy of an Object in typescript

Tags: typescript, copy, clone, deep-copy

I was trying to implement a deep clone function/class in my project.
I came across this article: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/deep-clone-an-object-and-preserve-its-type-with-typescript-d488c35e5574

After implementing this solution I always ran into the problem that the **Maximum call stack size has been exceeded**.

In the comments I then came across this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69368534/3757553

But this results in the same problem. I don't have enough reputation yet or else I would have asked in the comments of the answer myself.

As for my code it looks like this:

functions.ts File:

```
// copied function from stackoverflow
export const deepCopy: Function = <T>(source: T, preservePropertyDescriptor: boolean = false,
                                      ...excludedProperties: string[]): Mutable<T> => {
  return Array.isArray(source)
    ? source.map((item: T): Mutable<T> => deepCopy(item, preservePropertyDescriptor, excludedProperties))
    : source instanceof Date
     ? new Date(source.getTime())
     : source && typeof source === 'object'
       ? Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).reduce((obj: any, prop: string): Mutable<T> => {
           if (excludedProperties.includes(prop)) { // skip property
             return obj;
           } else {
             if (preservePropertyDescriptor) {
               Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, prop));
             }
             // @ts-ignore
             obj[prop] = deepCopy(source[prop], preservePropertyDescriptor, excludedProperties);
             return obj;
           }
         }, Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(source)))
       : source as Mutable<T>;
};
```

I then import and call the function in another file on a simple object:

```
import { deepCopy } from 'functions.ts'

const objCopy = deepCopy(objToCopy)
```

I also tried a simplified version of the function:

```
export const deepCopy: Function = <T>(source: T): Mutable<T> => {
    console.log(source)
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(source).reduce((obj: any, prop: string): Mutable<T> => {
        obj[prop] = deepCopy(source[prop])
        return obj
    }, Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(source)))
}
```

But again the same problem.

I have since found a different solution that works for the moment, ***but I'd really like to know what I'm doing wrong.***

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of your problem? I tried your code, and ignoring some type errors due to missing types, [it works in a simple case just fine.](https://tsplay.dev/mqQrrm) Maybe it only fails while copying certain objects? If so what objects are you copying?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w2EqrW) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.